# How to set the path to where python runs the code

Tags: python, path, set

I am following the LPTHW guide. When opening files I have to type `python ~/documents/ex1.py` .
That has run the script, however in Zed's guides he simply writes, `python ex1.py`.
When it came to ex25 it did not work at all. I then found out how to set the folder to serch in during that session.

```
$ python
import sys
sys.path.append("Path_Here")
```

How/where do I save the file so i don't have to type the whole path in or go through the above every time I want to run a script? Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Save it in `~`. Problem solved !

Comment: Please re-read [Exercise 0](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex0.html) and [Appendix A](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/appendixa.html) - you should be changing your working directory to the location of your Python files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at ~7:51 in [his video](http://youtu.be/k-SyGaRk8YY?t=7m51s), where he says you should change to the folder where you saved the script:

```
$ cd ~/documents
```

After that you will be able to do:

```
python ex1.py
```

Comment: You seriously saw the video before posting the answer?

Comment: Sure,:-). I am always looking for resources to recommend my friends, this one looks good.

Answer (score 0):

You're not looking for a python module, you're trying to run a *file*; python wouldn't know about that file, even if it was in your PYTHONPATH, since that is the path that python looks in when looking for modules that you can import. Really, you'll have to run python with a valid filename;

However, there's a way to do that: change your PYTHONPATH to contain the directory with ex1.py, and then call ex1 as a module:

```
python -m ex1
```

However, this might have unforeseeable side effects, so I'd just encourage you to either

```
cd ~/documents
python ex1.py
```

or

```
python ~/documents/ex1.py
```

since this is the way you open files.

Comment: Good answer, But the OP is asking where to save his file, So that he need not `cd` everytime

Answer (score -1):

I think that if your current directory is ~/documents, it should work.

Beside that, what you are looking for is os.getcwd()

```
import sys, os
sys.path.append(os.getcwd())
```